# webpack.DefinePlugin - unable to get any substitution to work

Tags: webpack

Webpack supports the substitution of constant expressions at build time via webpack.DefinePlugin

This is extremely useful for preprocessing the code in order to target different build environments.

However, despite countless experiments and research, I cannot get **any** substitution to take effect.

I do know that the plugin section is recognized by webpack , as the output is uglified.

My actual use case is far more complex, but the problem I am experiencing is demonstrated via the following  minimal code and configuration.

webpack 2.2.1

**test.js**

```
document.write  ("xx")
```

I wish to transform “xx” to "SOMETHING DIFFERENT"

webpack.config.js

```
var webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports = {

    plugins: [
   new webpack.DefinePlugin(
       {
            "xx" : JSON.stringify("SOMETHING DIFFERENT")
            }
       )
       , new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()
    ]

}
```

**Command line**

```
Webpack test.js out.js
```

**Output fragment…**

```
… t(t.s=1)}([function(n,t){document.write("xx")},function(n,t,r){r(0),n.exports=r(0)}]);
```

The xx is not replaced with SOMETHING DIFFERENT

Answer (score 3):

The `DefinePlugin` will only replace identifiers. You're trying to replace parts of a string, but strings aren't touched at all.

If you use:

```
document.write(xx)
```

you'll get the expected:

```
document.write("SOMETHING DIFFERENT");
```

Don't get confused by the quotes around `"xx"`, which are in fact not needed in this case, but are used to define keys that contain symbols which are not valid in an identifier. When the key is a valid identifier it works (it will automatically be converted to a string), otherwise you need to put it in quotes as any string can be used as a key. For example:

```
const obj = {
  xx: "works fine, quotes can be omitted around xx",
  x-2: "does not work and requires quotes, SyntaxError: Unexpected token -",
  "x-2": 'works again, with the key being 'x-2'"
}
```